# How to get data from group by result set based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am getting the data between 2 dates group by year and month. Now for debugging purpose, I want to fetch check data from group result for a particular month but I am not getting how to do that.

**Query:**

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(ActiveDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(ActiveDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS MyDate, 
    Count(*) AS Stats 
FROM JobListings
where CompanyID = 100
and Status = 'Active'
and (ActiveDate >= '9/1/2020' 
and ActiveDate <= '2/28/2021')
GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(ActiveDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(ActiveDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

This gives me the result like below:

```
MyDate       Stats
10-2020      3
11-2020      15
12 - 2020    4
and so on.
```

Now what I want is get the actual 3 records for "10-2020", so how do I inject a parent query to get the actual data from the group result set for particular month and year?

Comment: you have to write a separate query ( without grouping and filtered for that month-year)) to get the actual data

Comment: @eshirvana but the problem is I am getting a lot of data for "October" month. How do I get only those 3 data for "October" month which is included in group by result?

Comment: @eshirvana No you do not need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by this query, this should return only 3 records :

```
SELECT *
FROM JobListings
where 
    CompanyID = 100
    and Status = 'Active'
    and ActiveDate >= '10/01/2020' 
    and ActiveDate <= '11/01/2020'
```

well I add here instead of comments, try this and see what it returns:

```
select * 
, CAST(MONTH(ActiveDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(ActiveDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) Mydate
from JobListings
where CAST(MONTH(ActiveDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(ActiveDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) = '10-2020'
```

Comment: Actually this query gives me only 2 records and that group by is giving Count 3 for "October" and thats what I dont understand why there is a difference of 1 record

Comment: sorry October has 31 days , so it should be ok now

Comment: Sorry to say but still this gives me 2 records and not 3 and when I run for ActiveDate >= '9/1/2020' and ActiveDate <= '2/28/2021' then I am getting 3 records for "October". Thats why I wanted to inspect the data from group result for October month like which data it is taking from JobListing at least If I can get the JobListingID which is unique in that table

Comment: that can't be , then there is an issue somewhere in your data

Comment: Can i include JobListingID in the group by ? But I guess that will change the result right?

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused see my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229465/discussion-between-learning-overthinker-confused-and-eshirvana).

Answer (score 1):

You need a window aggregate here, and no `GROUP BY`.

Also, I advise you to use `EOMONTH` instead of splitting the date and casting like you have.

```sql
SELECT
    EOMONTH(ActiveDate),
    Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EOMONTH(ActiveDate) AS Stats,
    *
FROM JobListings
where 
    CompanyID = 100
    and Status = 'Active'
    and (ActiveDate >= '9/1/2020' 
    and ActiveDate <= '2/28/2021')
```

Comment: that changes the showing  result , he only needed a statement  for debugging purposes